# Windows Hello randomly disappears from the lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, windows-10-mobile, windows-hello, lumia-950

I use Windows Hello on my Lumia 950, but I've noticed that every once in a while the little "eye" icon has disappeared from the lock screen. The red LED also doesn't light up, it's like I never enabled Windows Hello. In Settings, everything seems normal, though. The only way to get it back is to restart the phone.

What's the problem? Simply a bug in Windows 10?

Comment: My mom has a 950 and has noticed the same thing. I'm guessing it's a Windows 10 bug, but don't know for certain.

Comment: Same here. SInce it's in beta, don't expect it to be working 100%

Comment: No, it's not still in beta. The build was "publicly released" via the 950 / 950XL. If MS is going to ship a phone with *any* version of an OS on it, it's not unreasonable to expect it to work correctly.

Comment: @Indrek, sorry, that was a mis-shot. Deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a very long time since I last experienced this bug, so I'm going to assume it got fixed in some update along the way.